# Mouse cursor that leaves trails only when button is pressed

Tags: windows-7, mouse, cursor

For a presentation I'm preparing I wan't to be able to have a mouse cursor that leaves a trail. But I only wan't it to leave a trail when the mouse button is pressed. It would also be nice to be able to change the cursor to a circle.

Does anyone know if there is an existing solution for this? The trail alternative in Windows always shows the trail.

And if anyone wonder - Why on earth would he want that? I'm going to demonstrate the user interface on a Windows Phone using the emulator (and also create videos). And it is really annoying for the viewer that he doesn't distinguish between when just moving the cursor och panning/flicking. And the circle is just more "fingerish" than a regular arrow pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to achieve what you ask for.

But you might instead use **Show location of pointer when I press the Ctrl key** to locate the mouse pointer by pressing the Ctrl key during the demo:

[image]